# Why exactly is Bourbaki difficult?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, axioms

I keep hearing people say that Bourbaki is difficult for most undergraduates but I still don't understand why. Surely if it starts from definitions/axioms then practically anyone should be able to understand it, let alone just graduate/advanced undergraduates. I didn't have any trouble reading Euclid's elements, so it has always baffled me as to why Bourbaki should be so difficult. The most familiar response I get is that Bourbaki is "abstract". What does this term actually mean?

Thanks in advance for answering my questions.

Comment: Did you read Euclid in the original Greek? Just curious.

Comment: I think it's a bit more ambitious and rigorous comparable undergrad books, but it's hardly intractable. Also, Euclid's ''Elements'' is very different from modern math books; its difficulty is in its outdated presentation and style rather than the inherent subject matter.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy it's in Ancient Greek, not Greek.

Comment: I suppose the main problem is motivation or the long way it takes until you arrive at something useful (e.g. a group or a field) from the axioms

Comment: @UserX Ancient Greek would be the original Greek.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy no that would be Ancient Greek.

Comment: It was in Greek when he wrote it, though.

Comment: Then difficult = "takes a long time to learn" sounds more reasonable.

Comment: «Surely if it starts from definitions/axioms then practically anyone should be able to understand it»

Well, no.

Comment: One thing to understand about Bourbaki is that they wanted to write an encyclpedia of the important mathematics known in the middle of the twentieth century. It is thus **not** a textbook. Most students are used to the textbook style of writing, thus making it more difficult to understand Bourbaki, even if exercises are included.